# Can't print Post parameters in Django

Tags: python, html, django, post

I want to check all params sent in POST so I've tried to print `request.POST.__dict__` and it print's only these two: `{'_encoding': 'utf-8', '_mutable': True}`

I'm sure that there is more `params` because it is tested before printed:

```
if 'input_text_area' in request.POST:
        print request.POST.__dict__
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try `request.body`? `request.POST` will only contain `form` data.

Comment: Exception Type: RawPostDataException
Exception Value: 
You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream This is what I get when try to print request.body

Comment: Can you show some more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print request.POST
```

should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`__dict__` access the attributes of the object, not its members. `request.POST` is a dict-like object; you access its members like any other dict. Printing `request.POST` on its own will show you what it contains.